# Mounting a large file in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, storage, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-secrets

We are running a pod in Kubernetes that needs to load a file during runtime. This file has the following properties:

- It is known at build time
- It should be mounted read-only by multiple pods (the same kind)
- It might change (externally to the cluster) and needs to be updated
- For various reasons (security being the main concern) the file cannot be inside the docker image
- It is potentially quite large, theoretically up to 100 MB, but in practice between 200kB - 10MB.

We have considered various options:

- Creating a persistent volume, mount the volume in a temporary pod to write (update) the file, unmount the volume, and then mount it in the service with ROX (Read-Only Multiple) claims. This solution means we need downtime during upgrade, and it is hard to automate (due to timings).
- Creating multiple secrets using the secrets management of Kubernetes, and then "assemble" the file before loading it in an init-container or something similar.

Both of these solutions feels a little bit hacked - is there a better solution out there that we could utilize for solving this?

Comment: are you on cloud or on prem ?

Comment: We are targeting multiple different environments, but first steps are done in Google using GKE

Comment: Why is there downtime in the first solution? There is no downtime in the second solution? Is no downtime a requirement?

Comment: No downtime would be nice, not a hard requirement.. just trying to see if there exist a better solution

Comment: Why do you need a "temporary pod" with the PV solution? Why can't you just have a PV given its contents are known at build time? If you really need this, you can create a 1-off Job that has a read/write PVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a shared filesystem that supports Read/Write Multiple Pods.
Here is a link to the CSI Drivers which can be used with Kubernetes and provide those access:
https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/drivers.html

Ideally, you need a solution that is not an appliance, and can run anywhere meaning it can run in the cloud or on-prem.

The platforms that could work for you are Ceph, GlusterFS, and Quobyte (*Disclaimer, I work for Quobyte*)

Comment: We have since moved on from this problem, but your solution would be exactly what we would need. Thanks.